# Search in all json's elements with lodash.js

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

friens i have object json :

```
  var companies= [
    { id: 1, name: "Test Company", admin: "Test Admin" },
    { id: 2, name: "Another Company", admin: "Test Admin", country: 'Spain' },
    { id: 3, name: "New Company", admin: "Admin 4" },
    { id: 4, name: "Free Company", admin: "Jhon Miller", city: 'New York' }
];
```

and I am writing a function for return new json with elements that I pass as parameters(filter). I make a simple

```
   function searchBooks(companies,filter){
    var result;
      if (typeof filter=== "undefined" ||  filter.length==0) {
          result = companies;
      } else {
        result = _.filter(companies, function (c) {
         return _.includes(_.lowerCase(c.name),_.lowerCase(filter));
       });
     }
 }
```

With my function I can only filter by name, My question is: how i can filter by name,admin,country,city  except by id, for example if you pass 4 in the variable should return :

{ id: 3, name: "New Company", admin: "Admin 4" }

or if I search iLl should return :

{ id: 4, name: "Free Company", admin: "Jhon Miller", city: 'New York' }

Thanks

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org/), it's an array of objects. JSON is a data exchange format that is formatted like a subset of JS. The string `'[{"id":1},{"id":2}]'` is data formatted in JSON, it could be [parsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) into a JS array: `[{id: 1}, {id: 2}]`. It might seem like semantics, but it is an important distinction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The search function below makes use of [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) to get the matched objects from the `text` search. To determine if an object is a match for the searched `text`, we use [some()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) against all values of each object in the collection. The `some()` method tests each of the values in the object in a lower-cased form against the lower-cased form of the searched `text` using [includes()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#includes).

Note that I used [toLower()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toLower), as opposed to [lowerCase()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#lowerCase) since the latter converts a string into their lower-case format as separated words while the former completely converts the entire string regardless of the string's case-format -- you can choose to switch it otherwise, depending on your requirements.

**Update**: I added an exclude parameter as a way to [omit()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) certain properties when testing object values from the searched `text`.

```
function searchByText(collection, text, exclude) {
  text = _.toLower(text);
  return _.filter(collection, function(object) {
    return _(object).omit(exclude).some(function(string) {
      return _(string).toLower().includes(text);
    });
  });
}
console.log(searchByText(companies, '4'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, 'iLl'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, '4', ['id']));
```

```js
var companies = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test Company",
    admin: "Test Admin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Another Company",
    admin: "Test Admin",
    country: 'Spain'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "New Company",
    admin: "Admin 4"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Free Company",
    admin: "Jhon Miller",
    city: 'New York'
  }
];

function searchByText(collection, text, exclude) {
  text = _.toLower(text);
  return _.filter(collection, function(object) {
    return _(object).omit(exclude).some(function(string) {
      return _(string).toLower().includes(text);
    });
  });
}

console.log(searchByText(companies, '4'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, 'iLl'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, '4', ['id']));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Here's a compositional version of the solution above using [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) and [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flow)

```
function searchByText(collection, text, exclude) {
  return _.filter(collection, _.flow(
    _.partial(_.omit, _, exclude),
    _.partial(
      _.some, _,
      _.flow(_.toLower, _.partial(_.includes, _, _.toLower(text), 0))
    )
  ));
}

console.log(searchByText(companies, '4'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, 'iLl'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, '4', ['id']));
```

```js
var companies = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Test Company",
    admin: "Test Admin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Another Company",
    admin: "Test Admin",
    country: 'Spain'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "New Company",
    admin: "Admin 4"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Free Company",
    admin: "Jhon Miller",
    city: 'New York'
  }
];

function searchByText(collection, text, exclude) {
  return _.filter(collection, _.flow(
    _.partial(_.omit, _, exclude),
    _.partial(
      _.some, _,
      _.flow(_.toLower, _.partial(_.includes, _, _.toLower(text), 0))
    )
  ));
}

console.log(searchByText(companies, '4'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, 'iLl'));
console.log(searchByText(companies, '4', ['id']));
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @ryeballar . Your 2 solutions are very elegant but i need to know how can exclude ID for filter ?  because if i write 4 show 2 registers and should show 1 only : { id: 3, name: "New Company", admin: "Admin 4" },

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is 100% valid.

Answer (score 0):

How could search on every property with the same way, specifying your potential searching keys, see `searchBooksSpecificProperties`

Alternative, if you always want to search on all the fields you can get the keys on every item with `_.keys()`, see `searchBooks`

```js
var companies= [
    { id: 1, name: "Test Company", admin: "Test Admin" },
    { id: 2, name: "Another Company", admin: "Test Admin", country: 'Spain' },
    { id: 3, name: "New Company", admin: "Admin 4" },
    { id: 4, name: "Free Company", admin: "Jhon Miller", city: 'New York' }
];

function searchBooks(companies, filter){
  var result;
    if (typeof filter=== "undefined" ||  filter.length==0) {
        result = companies;
    } else {
      result = _.filter(companies, function (c) {
        var cProperties = _.keys(c);
        _.pull(cProperties, 'id');
        return _.find(cProperties, function(property) {
          if (c[property]) {
            return _.includes(_.lowerCase(c[property]),_.lowerCase(filter));
          }          
        });         
     });
   }
   return result;
 }

 console.log('searchBooks:');
 console.log(searchBooks(companies, 'Admin 4'))
 console.log(searchBooks(companies, 'York'))
 
function searchBooksSpecificProperties(properties, companies, filter){
  var searchSpecificProperties = _.isArray(properties);
  var result;
    if (typeof filter=== "undefined" ||  filter.length==0) {
        result = companies;
    } else {
      result = _.filter(companies, function (c) {
        var cProperties = searchSpecificProperties ? properties : _.keys(c);
        return _.find(cProperties, function(property) {
          if (c[property]) {
            return _.includes(_.lowerCase(c[property]),_.lowerCase(filter));
          }          
        });         
     });
   }
   return result;
 }
 console.log('searchBooksSpecificProperties:');
 console.log(searchBooksSpecificProperties(['name', 'admin'], companies, 'Admin 4'))
 console.log(searchBooksSpecificProperties(['name', 'admin'], companies, 'York'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Apostolidis but how i can make this with function that recive 2 parameters only ? ,without properties

Comment: I changed my answer adding the 2 different functions. You can see the `searchBooks()` and `searchBooksSpecificProperties()`

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys()` is the key ;)

Try this :

```js
var companies= [
    { id: 1, name: "Test Company", admin: "Test Admin" },
    { id: 2, name: "Another Company", admin: "Test Admin", country: 'Spain' },
    { id: 3, name: "New Company", admin: "Admin 4" },
    { id: 4, name: "Free Company", admin: "Jhon Miller", city: 'New York' }
];

function searchBooks(filter){
    var result;
      if (typeof filter=== "undefined" ||  filter.length==0) {
          result = companies;
      } else {
        result = _.filter(companies, function (c) {

         // This part will transform every property value in a single string.
         var searchIn = Object.keys(c).reduce(function(res, val) { return (val !== 'id')?res+c[val]:res }, '');
         return _.includes(_.lowerCase(searchIn),_.lowerCase(filter));
       });
     }
     console.log(result)
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onKeyUp="searchBooks(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thanks you @SteevePitis , your solution is valid but i need to know how i can exclude ID for filter,because if i write 4 show 2 registers and should show 1 only.

Comment: If you want to show only the first result then you just have to `return result[0]`

Comment: I know this, but my question is if can exclude id when you search . Imagine that other register have "4" , should return 2 registers no 3 . Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand what you want.
You want to show all result except result with the id `X` (2, for exemple) ?

Comment: Oh I think I got it, you want to remove the key 'id' from the search list ?